# How to dynamically insert an element with Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a dynamic [listview using mobile kendo ui](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/listview). I understand that when I append things to the DOM I have to initialize the element, if I were to use jQuery, I'd do something like

```
$('#list').append(newElementStr);
$('#list').trigger('create');
```

here's an example of what I'm trying to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ab3Yu/

you can see that the dynamically inserted element looks different from the other list items, how do I initialize it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is missing http://jsfiddle.net/Ab3Yu/2/

```
$('#list').append('<li><a href="#" class="km-listview-link" data-role="listview-link">' + 'Dynamic Item' + '</a></li>');
$('#list').append('<li><a href="#">' + 'Dynamic Item' + '</a></li>');​
```

### Demo regarding add items to ListView

On the [how do i use listtview of kendo-ui-web](http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/howto-use-the-listview-of-kendo-ui-web)  is link to a [demo loading twitter data into a web-listview](http://jsfiddle.net/jbristowe/3w7ru/light/). Since the mobile listview has also a [datasource property](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/listview) this could work for mobile list view as well

Comment: This feels somehow like a hack to me, aren't there any initialize methods that I can call on the element that automatically generates the classes it needs like the first four list items in my example?

Comment: I am uncertain about the real intent of your question. As far as i understand you wanted to add an element that looks the same as the others. I did provide a way for that. Now you are asking if there are multiple (nicer) ways.

Comment: if I were to use jQuery to attempt the same thing <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li> would translate to <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="acura.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Acura</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>  do you see why I say it's a hack?

Comment: I tried the methods in the link you had provided in your update: http://jsfiddle.net/Ab3Yu/8/  I was not able to get the desired result without adding the km-listview-link class, also the `.kendoListView` doesn't seem to be a mobile method.

Comment: guess a hack is better than nothing, thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 1):

You can always add data on the list's DataSource. Here's how I transferred all items from one list to another

```
function moveAllLeft() {
    var listView2 = $("#listView2").data("kendoListView");
    listView2.element.children().each(function() {
        listView2.remove($(this));
        var that = $(this);
        dataSource.add({
            ProductName : that[0].innerText
        });
    });
}

function moveAllRight() {
    var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
    listView.element.children().each(function() {
        listView.remove($(this));
        var that = $(this);
        dataSource2.add({
            ProductName : that[0].innerText
        });
    });
}
```

where dataSource is the first list's datasource, and dataSource2 the second list's datasource.